# tkinter display new frame from menu

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, dynamic, frame

I'm trying to write my fisrt script in python & tkinter.

I block to display a new frame from a function (**def onDisplay**) when a click is made from menu bar button, but nothing append.
No error is display :-(

The new frame is made with dynamic checkboxes from text files:
txt file:

```
item1
item2
...
item100
```

A screen of the GUI:

[image]

Here my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Checkbutton, Text, TOP, BOTH, X, N, LEFT, BooleanVar
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry
import glob

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        #self.display_srv()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Submenu")

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst1", command=self.onDisplay)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst2")
        submenu.add_command(label="lst3")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Listing', menu=submenu, underline=0)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)

    #The frame i tried to display
    def onDisplay(self):
        self.master.title("display it")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)
        path = '/root/liste/*.txt'
        files=glob.glob(path)
        count = 0
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    # Need to split all item by 10
                    Checkbutton(self, text=item.rstrip()).grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                    count += 1


    def onClick(self):
        if self.var.get() == True:
            self.master.title("Checkbutton")
        else:
            self.master.title("")

    def onExit(self):

        self.quit()


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("850x550+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Many thanks for any help

Regards,

Comment: What  have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `files=glob.glob(path)` is doing what you think?

Comment: yes, i used this part of this code in a standalone script, without menu bar.

Comment: That code, mixing `.pack(...` with `.grid(...`,  will never work. Take the tour and reread how it works [tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm)

Comment: ok, thank you for the link stovfl. I replace by .pack: `Checkbutton(self, text=item.rstrip()).pack` but the issue is the same.. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're mixing `grid` and `pack` in the same parent container. You are calling `pack` on `frame1` but you are calling `grid` on the checkbuttons, and they both have a master or parent of `self`.

That can't work, because each of `grid` and `pack` will try to resize the container according to it's rules, triggering the other one to reconfigure according to it's rules, and so on until the end of time.

So, simply changing your call of `.grid(...)` to `.pack(...)` on the checkbuttons will fix that problem.

My guess is that you intended to put the checkbuttons inside `frame1`. If that's the case, you need to specify `frame1` as the master for the checkbuttons. For readability and ease of debugging I also recommend placing the call to `grid` on a separate line. With that, you can continue to use `grid` for the checkbuttons and `pack` for everything else.

```
cb = Checkbutton(frame1, text=item.rstrip())
cb.grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
```

Comment: Many thanks Bryan, i understand better now. I started to use python since few days.. :). I got another issue on my code. I will create a new topic on **Stack** today or tomorrow. If is possible for you to take look please.I search how to get the values of each selected items.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the correct code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Checkbutton, Text, TOP, BOTH, X, N, LEFT, BooleanVar
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry
import glob

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        #self.display_srv()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Submenu")

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst1", command=self.onDisplay)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst2")
        submenu.add_command(label="lst3")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Listing', menu=submenu, underline=0)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
    def onDisplay(self):
        self.master.title("display it")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)
        path = '/root/liste/*.txt'
        files=glob.glob(path)
        count = 0
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    cb = Checkbutton(frame1, text=item.rstrip())
                    cb.grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                    count += 1

    def onClick(self):
        if self.var.get() == True:
            self.master.title("Checkbutton")
        else:
            self.master.title("")

    def onExit(self):

        self.quit()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("850x550+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```